# Is it possible to check Statuscodes with nightwatch especially for assets like images

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I use Nightwatch.js to run my frontend tests. Now im at a point where i need to know if an image is succesfully loaded. Is it possible to check the statuscodes of the assets loaded by the webpage?

Thanks in advance.